# C fscanf doesn't load integers but loads strings

Tags: c

This functon loads strings properly but doesnt load integers. Why?

```
void loadaj(){

        FILE * save;
        save=fopen("sejv.txt","r");

        if(save==NULL){
            slovkaj("\n Nema spremljenog lika\n Stisni bilo koju tipku za nastavak...",5);
            getch();
            system("cls");
        }
        if(save!=NULL){

        rewind(save);
        fscanf(save,"%s %s %[^\n] %[^\n] %s %s %s %s %s",ime,klasa,oruzje,strijele,glava,ruke,jezgra,noge,stit);
        fflush(save);
        //fscanf(save,"%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",ziva,ziva2,ziva3,xp,xpZaLvlUp,maxVitalnost,vitalnost,novci,stetaOruzja,oklopGlava,oklopRuke,oklopJezgra,oklopNoge,oklopStit,stetaStrijela,knjiga,teleportacijaDaljina,vjetarDaljina,vatraSteta,vodaSteta,ledSteta,teleportacijaXp,teleportacijaLvl,vjetarXp,vjetarLvl,vodaXp,vodaLvl,ledXp,ledLvl,smrtLvl,grad);
        fscanf(save,"%d",ziva);
        savePostoji=true;
        }

        fclose(save);
}
```

Comment: Using `fflush()` to input stream invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Perhaps the format of the `save` file doesn't match your rather long `fscanf` format. You could get better diagnostics if you read the strings or at least the lines individually and checked the result value of `fscanf`.

Comment: OT: In general it's a good idea to "program in english", i.e. use english function and variable names. Only printouts should be in local language.

Comment: The second `if` statement is completely redundant.

Comment: We need more details. What is the content of `sejv.txt`? What exactly is consumed/what not? Voted to close.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Well - not redundant as there is no return in the `if (save == NULL)` part :-/

Comment: @4386427 True, but at least the second condition test is redundant. Just `else` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf` works normally for integers too. It is `fflush` that is causing the problem. `fflush` is clearing the input buffer here.

Comment: It's UB to call `fflush()` on an input stream.